# Is this ideal CodeIgniter App Architecting?

Tags: php, codeigniter, architecture

I have a pretty good handle on using models to make database calls and handing the data off to...

I understand views and ideal usage. My general thoughts are to create the following for each section (for the most part):

PEOPLE

```
  - controller
  - model
  - view(s) // add, edit, profile, etc
  - library // specific logic and output
```

then when I want to access people related data;  Say from my `BORROWER` controller I’ll call the `people library function` and load the appropriate `people view` into the `BORROWER controller` and into its view. AND, same naturally for `PEOPLE` logic. DRY.

Is this ideal?

Comment: Seems so, but with the library, what logic wouldn't make sense in the model, and what output wouldn't make sense in a view?

Comment: Agreed. Libraries are better suited for classing out common controller logic. Think of models as the place where you not only retrieve data, but format it for use in controllers/views.

Comment: @landons you're right. I have used the model for logic. But CodeIgniter writes, _The Model represents your data structures. Typically... retrieve, insert, and update information in your database._ 



So hence the question. AND looking at the CodeIgniter flowchart; it seems that's the way it was intended. Though, I get CodeIgniter works pretty much however anyone wants it to.


Currently I'm just getting and sending data arrays from the Model. I use the Controller and Library items to process data and logic, then send it to the View.

Comment: Yes, you can use it however you want, but that's different from "ideal."  Ideally, libraries are for common functionality that's independent from the type of object using it.  That's why file uploads, image manipulation, etc. are considered "libraries," as they're not specific to the implementation (like "People," which is a model). I would answer that your approach "works" but is not "ideal."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using HMVC extension for CI where you can develop on modular approach for MVC. This will allow you to load application modules with its own controllers, models and views. The modules can call any other module and can load models of other modules. Have a look in [here](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc)

Comment: Do you use it? Sounds pretty cool... "_Modular HMVC means modular MVC triads. Modular Separation and Modular Extensions allows related controllers, models, libraries, views, etc. to be grouped together in module directories and used like a mini application. But, Modular Extensions goes one step further and allows those modules to “talk” to each other. You can get controller output without having to go out through the http interface again._"

Comment: Yes, ever since I started with HMVC, everything came to sense. I am using for larger applications. Saves alot of time too.